# what controls a CSS transform's horizontal movement?

Tags: css, css-transforms

I found a pure CSS mobile burger menu solution on [codepen](https://codepen.io/erikterwan/pen/EVzeRP), and I altered the code with

`transform: translate(-200%, 0);`

```css
/* Mobile Menu */
#menuToggle {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
#menuToggle a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #232323;
    transition: color 0.3s ease;
}
#menuToggle a:hover {color: tomato;}
#menuToggle input {
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 32px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -7px;
    left: -5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0; /* hide this */
    z-index: 2; /* and place it over the hamburger */
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
#menuToggle span {
    display: block;
    width: 33px;
    height: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    position: relative;
    background: #cdcdcd;
    border-radius: 3px;
    z-index: 1;
    transform-origin: 4px 0px;
    transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0), background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0), opacity 0.55s ease;
}
#menuToggle span:first-child {transform-origin: 0% 0%;}
#menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2) {transform-origin: 0% 100%;}
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
    background: #232323;
}
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(3) {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(2) {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
}
#mobile-menu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    margin: -100px 0 0 -50px;
    padding: 50px;
    padding-top: 125px;
    background: #ededed;
    list-style-type: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform: translate(-200%, 0);
    transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0);
}
#mobile-menu li {
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-size: 22px;
}
#menuToggle input:checked ~ ul {transform: none;}
/* End Mobile Menu */
```

```html
    <!--      Mobile Menu          -->
    <!--    Made by Erik Terwan    --> 
    <!--   24th of November 2015   --> 
    <!--        MIT License        -->
    <nav role="navigation" id="nav-mobile-menu">
      <div id="menuToggle">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span></span> <span></span> <span></span>
        <ul id="mobile-menu">
          <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#history">History</a></li>
          <li><a href="#campaigns">Campaigns</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!--      End Mobile Menu          -->
```

On the [live site](https://s.doig.com.au/edu/), I see the following when clicking on the burger icon:

[image]

What is going wrong with the `transform: translate(-200%, 0);` transform?

Help appreciated.

Comment: Where did you change this? You gave us a bunch of CSS, but didn't tell us what element you changed.

Comment: _“On the live site, I see the following when clicking on the burger icon:”_ - “and I am not happy with that, because instead I expected to see ______” (fill in the blanks.)

Comment: Also, you have two questions with the exact same title.

Comment: @disinfor `and I altered the code with transform: translate(-200%, 0);`

Comment: @Steve So we have to go through your CSS block to find it? Why wouldn't you tell us WHAT you altered, so we don't have to hunt? Also, as CBroe points out, what are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your toggle-menu is hide, first of all you need to display it and thien try this:

```
#menuToggle {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

#mobile-menu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    margin: -100px 0 0 -100px;
    padding: 50px;
        padding-top: 50px;
    padding-top: 125px;
    background: #ededed;
    list-style-type: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform: translate(-200%, 0);
    transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0);
}
```